# Compile view with compilation error, noot show errors command says no errors

Tags: oracle

I have added to my view one field.

When I compile it with sqlplus I get warnings:

> Warning: View created with compilation errors.
>
> Warning: View created with compilation errors.

When I then run show errors it displays:

> No errors.

Any idea if I have errors or not?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM view_name` And probably it is `invalid` so you will get error.

Comment: can you share your view script?

Comment: there is a function, which I have no access to. I have to talk to boss, sorry

Comment: Are you creating the view in a different schema to your own? Either  explicitly, or by setting current_schema? That would stop the errors being visible to you in `user_errors`, or with `show errors` unless you give some arguments. You might beable to see them in `all_errors` instead.

Answer (score 5):

this will help you:

```
SHOW ERRORS VIEW view_name
```

or

```
SHOW ERRORS VIEW owner.view_name
```

(if you're not the owner of the view).

Comment: This is very useful. Why don't SQL Developer just display the error along with it's compilation warning...

Answer (score 0):

Need to be more careful, when add fields to view. Development server has many databases, and if they are not refreshed regularly, then we miss some recent changes, like in my  case one database didn't have one field in the table, for underlying view, and I couldn't compile it